# jq script file not getting the key/value pair

Tags: json, linux, parsing, command-line, jq

I would like to put all jq filters inside a text file and use the `jq -L` option to execute the filters. However, I can't get this simple thing working.

Inside my `sample2.json` file, I have:

```
{
        "a": 86,
        "b": 99
}
```

[image]

Inside my `json2csv` file, I have:

```
.["a"]
```

[image]

When I do:

```
cat sample.json | jq -L json2csv
```

The output is the whole sample.json file, like this:

[image]

but I would expect the output is only `86`because:

[image]

How do I change the content of the `json2csv` file so I can only get the `86` in the output?
I am using jq 1.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jq -f json2csv` instead.

From `man jq`:

> -Ldirectory / -L directory:
>
> Prepend directory to the search list for modules. If this option is used then no builtin search list is used. See the  section  on  modules
> below.

Compare this to:

> -f filename / --from-file filename:
>
> Read filter from the file rather than from a command line, like awk´s -f option. You can also use # to make comments.